# How to safely remove all files (including hidden files) from current directory (after cding to that directory)?

Tags: rm

How to safely remove all files (including hidden files) from current directory (**after `cd`ing to that directory**)?

As far as I know, `cd RELEVANT_DIR && rm *` won't remove hidden files.

I would assume `cd RELEVANT_DIR && rm -rf ./*` is the right command but I might be wrong.

### Update

I do want to remove directories (and possible symlinks and basically everything in the directory) as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that question has been asked before. See [What's the fastest way to remove all files & subfolders in a directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/277214) for an answer to your specific question. I'll try and find a closer duplicate.

Comment: Have you considered using `find` with `-delete`?

Comment: Why would you use `rm -rf` for hidden files? Do you also want to remove directories? What does "safely" mean here?

Comment: @FelixJN after roaima's answer yes.

Comment: @terdon I understood `rm -rf` removes everything, including directories with the possible exception of hidden files. I do want to remove directories; about safely I am not sure myself, just something conventional.

Comment: Well, `-f` is as far from safe as it gets. To remove directories, you just need `-r`. See `man find`. The `-f` is to force remove even if the files are non-writeable by you.

Comment: Oh and @terdon one more thing, by safe I also meant "not very potentially confusing" which I think `rm *` can be, I mean just `rm /*` can possibly destory a system, just a "typo" and generally there are no warnings, as you know.

Comment: @cautionisadvised `rm /*` will do nothing unless you run it as root. And, even then, on most systems that will just remove a few symlinks that can easily be recreated. `rm -r /*` would be dangerous when run as root, yes. And there are some warnings, but using `-f` disables them which is why `-f` is not "safe" by any definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've referenced `rm -rf *` I've assume you don't just mean that you want to delete files, but that you want to delete all content including directories.

With `bash`

```
cd "RELEVANT_DIR" && ( shopt -s dotglob; rm -r * )
```

Otherwise with [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) tools

```
cd "RELEVANT_DIR" && (
    find . ! -type d -delete
    find . -depth -path './*' -type d -exec rmdir {} +
)
```

In this example omit the second `find` if you want to leave any directory structure intact.

Comment: Whatever method you use, try replacing `rm` with `ls` - this will give you some idea of the effect of your command.

Comment: @JeremyBoden not quite. Consider a directory called `dir`. Now `rm -r dir` will delete `dir` as expected, but `ls dir` will list the _contents_ of `dir` rather than `dir` itself. (Consider also that `dir` might be one of the values expanded from the use of `*`.) A better approach is to prefix the command with `echo`, for example here `echo rm -r *`